# How to generate register url for other user

Tags: url, .net-core

I want to make an application using .net core 5.0. users will register and login. Users who register and log in will create a reference url for other users, and I want to direct users who registered with this url to the registration page and write who produced the link. How can I do one and which library should I use? can you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

controller

```
    public IActionResult Register(string userReference = null)
    {
        ViewData["userReference"] = userReference;
        return View();
    }
    
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string userReference)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Random generator = new Random();
            String autoRefCode = generator.Next(0, 1000000).ToString("D6");

            if (userReference != null)
            {
                var userQuery = _context.Where(x => x.Reference = userReference); // other user ref

                // code
            }

            var user = new User
            {
                UserName = model.Email,
                Email = model.Email,
                Name = model.Name,
                Surname = model.Surname,
                Reference = autoRefCode
            };


            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "customer"); // role
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false); 
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    private IActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }
    }
```

class

```
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {

        public string Email { get; set; }


        public string Name { get; set; }


        public string Surname { get; set; }


        public string Reference { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I am posting the code using QueryString and in cshtml I have created the link with string operations. I don't know if it true method?